# How to Import or copy the input controls from 1 topic to another?

Tags: ireport

I created a topic using ireport, there are over 10 parameter inputs to the topic. In-order to properly work the parameters we have to create all input controls manually, similar input controls are available in another topic, I was thinking coping the input controls from the old report to new, seems like there is no copy option available in ireport 4.1.1.

Is there a better way to import or copy the input controls from 1 topic to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your report from which you want to copy parameters.

Go to Window --> Report Inspector

This will open a new tab Report Inspector , from there in Parameter section all the parameters will be listed right click on the parameters which you want to copy(you can also select multiple) and open other report in which you want to copy and paste it in Parameter section.

Comment: Yes, parameters are copied successfully, however, input controls are not copied, When you go to the Repository navigator, there are no input controls are created.

Comment: After copying input parameters in iReport you have to add in JasperReport server manually one by one.